# Obtaining the corresponding x,y,z values from pyqtgraph.image plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pyqtgraph

I have a sequence of images that are produced with the following Python (2.7) code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
data = np.ones((230,10,10)) #for example; not quite the data that resulted in this image, but the numbers themselves are not the focus
img = pg.image(data)
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

How do I obtain the corresponding 'x' value from the bottom plot? Additionally, how do I obtain the corresponding (x,y) coordinate from each of the squares in the upper plot?

Various answers on StackOverflow focus on "ImageView", but I am trying to avoid it if I can - I cannot produce a similar plot for some reason with ImageView - nothing comes out and Python just freezes. I am also new to PyQtGraph.

[image: Output from pyqtgraph.image]

Comment: Please clarify your question, what exactly do you want?

Comment: To be able to hover over the plots (either of the gridded one, or the graphical one) and obtain the corresponding coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pg.ImageView is actually the same as pg.image](http://pyqtgraph.org/documentation/functions.html#pyqtgraph.image) It creates an image view inside an image window

So try the following to get your code running with ImageView

```
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
data = np.ones((230,10,10))
imv = pg.ImageView()
imv.setImage(data)
imv.show()
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

Regarding the coordinates, the plot at the bottom is produced from a [Region of Interest (ROI)](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/roi.html) to get the x and y coordinates you will need to add a ROI to the image.

```
roi = pg.ROI([0,0],[1,1],pen=pg.mkPen('r',width=2))
imv.addItem(roi)
def getcoordinates(roi):
    data2,xdata = roi.getArrayRegion(data,imv.imageItem,returnMappedCoords=True)
    print(xdata)
roi.sigRegionChanged.connect(getcoordinates)
```

This will now print out the coordinates over which the ROI is hovering

Note: Above code is python 3.7 as that's what I'm using. So you'll have to adapt some things to python 2.7

Comment: Note: the above code is very basic, a much better example would use a classes to handle everything.